# Meteor Helper using query based on reactive variable

Tags: meteor, helper

I'm trying to use a helper that should return a Collection specifying a subset of the whole Collection with `$in` using a reactive array from [`templates:array`](https://github.com/meteortemplates/array/).

I have

```
var tags = new ReactiveArray();
```

and on some event I change the contents of the array, something along the lines of

```
tags.pushArray(note.tags);
```

(or maybe I should use `.set()`?)

My helper is

```
Template.editor.helpers({
    tagslist() {
        return Tags.find({ _id: { $in : tags }});
    }, 
});
```

But then I get an exception in `meteor.js:1010` which looks like this

```
if (allArgumentsOfTypeString)
   console.log.apply(console, [Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, " ")]);
```

In the stack there is `compileValueSelector`. This seems to indicate that the compilation of the helper is not content with what it finds.

I've also tried to make `tags` a template local instance, and adding `.get()` to the `tags` in the helper query. But with the same result.

Where should I start looking? Am I using ReactiveArray correctly? Is it possible to do what I want, namely have a reactive query based on an ReactiveArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally have not used ReactiveArray but I assume this same pattern would work. I stick to using ReactiveVar so here is an example that should get you going in the right direction.

```
Template.editor.onCreated(function () {
    const instance = this;
    instance.tags = new ReactiveVar([]);
});

Template.editor.helpers({
    tagslist() {
        const tags = Template.instance().tags.get();
        return Tags.find({ _id: { $in : tags }});
    }
});

Template.editor.events({
    'click .tag'(event, instance){
        const tag = this;
        const tags = instance.tags.get();
        tags.push(tag);
        instance.tags.set(tags);
    }
});
```

Comment: Re: your comment about `_id`. The `tags` variable contains the id:s of the Tags that I want to retrieve. Am I doing that wrong with `{ _id : { $in : tags }}`? In mongodb it seems to do what I want...

Comment: Also, I used a module scoped variable for `tags`, instead of a template instance field, since I need to call the "loading" code from outside the template. Doesn't that work?

Comment: You can use a module scoped variable and it should work exactly the same but keep in mind you may have to clear the array of it's data when page navigation occurs depending on how your application works.

Comment: I made it work with this pattern. Haven’t made any further efforts using ReactiveArray. Prbly have to read up on it.